# How are values compared when appending a dot to an instruction

Tags: assembly, powerpc

I am relatively new to assembly and PowerPC assembly in particular, so please bear with me on this question. I have looked around but haven't really found an accurate answer as to how exactly values are compared when appending a dot to an instruction, such as this:

```
clrlwi. r0, r0, 29   # clear left word immediate
```

Does this compare the original value of `r0` with the value calculated after clearing the bits, or is it the equivalent of something like `if (variable)` in a programming language? On [this page](http://wiibrew.org/wiki/Assembler_Tutorial), all it says is that appending a dot is the equivalent of

```
cmpwi rD, 0
```

But it's unclear to me what exactly this compares the register to because their syntax doesn't exactly show if a value is a register number or an immediate integer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dot means that the `CR0` flags (bits 0..3 of `CR`) will be updated based on the **result** of the instruction.

> `cr0` is used for the results of fixed-point computation instructions, which use non-immediate operands (with a few exceptions). The result of the computation is compared with zero, and the appropriate bits are set (negative, zero, or positive).
>   **To indicate in a computational instruction that you want it to set `cr0`, you simply add a period (`.`) to the end of the instruction.** For example, `add 4, 5, 6` adds register 5 to register 6 and stores the result in register 4, without setting any status bits in `cr0`. However, `add. 4, 5, 6` does the same thing, but sets the bits in `cr0` based on the computed value.

`CR0` bits:

```
0: Negative (LT) - This bit is set when the result is negative
1: Positive (GT) - This bit is set when the result is positive (and not zero)
2: Zero (EQ)     - This bit is set when the result is zero
3: Summary overflow (SO) - This is a copy of the final state of XER[SO] at completion of the instruction
```

[(source)](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-powasm3/)